# Jupyter ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, windows, jupyter

I have downloaded peewee and have it in my current directory, but jupyter cannot find it. 
Any ideas?

my jupyter notebook:
[image]

location of the peewee file:
[image: location of the peewee file:]

Comment: `pip install peewee` isn't good enough? Also `from peewee import *` and `import peewee` is a bit redundant

Comment: i tried pip - no luck. thanks on the import-didnt know that

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? Errors? Pip isn't installed?

Answer (score 5):

Since my Ipython notebook was in a different location than the Lib file, i needed to direct to it like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\MySQLdb')
```